# java- how can I read a text file containing multiple lines of integers and double values and then store into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have a text file which contains the following format

```
AcountNumber AccountBalance
```

AccountNumber is an integer and AccountBalance is a double.

In another file, I have the following format

```
Item Price
```

Item is a string and Price is a double.

So how can I read these types of lines and then store the values into an array?

Comment: are your data types all objects or primitive data, with the exception of the String Item of course?

Answer (score 0):

```
while there are lines to read
    read line
    split line
    do something with first part
    do something with second part
end while
```

or if you want to manipulate with line as whole you can

```
while there are lines to read
    read line
    convert line into pair
    do something with a pair
end while
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the respective parsing wrapper for the strings that will be read an `tokenised` using the `delimiter`. Handle the `Exceptions` properly in your code
Here is some introductory part about the same

For first requirement what you have to do is
This line will be split using the space delimiter and then you can work on the array tokens like this :-

As the first argument is integer you can parse it using

`Integer.parseInt(token[0])`

As the second argument is Double you can parse it using

`Double.parseDouble(token[1])`

Similarly you have to do for the second input also i.e for String and Double

Answer (score 0):

You would create  your four arrays, `int[]`, `double[] (for account balance)`, `double[] (for price)`, `String[]`. Please note that you must instantiate your arrays with the proper length and your own significant names before you start adding values to them.

Then two while loops, one for each file structured with Scanner read statements such that they match the pattern you have in your text file format. For example, what you would have for the first file would be

```
while(Scanner.hasNext()){ //hasNext() is a boolean method that checks if there is more input in the file
intAccountNumber[x] = Scanner.nextInt();//Pulls next int in a line, stays on line
doubleAccountBal[x] = Scanner.nextDouble();//pulls next double stays on line
x++;
}
```

Note that is this an example of what the first loop for your first file should/could look like. You would implement the same logic with the other text file simply switching out [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) methods in the example to fit the right type of data you are storing and put in the correct arrays that match the data that you are storing.

If you have any questions, just shoot me a comment.